# Como preencher uma ArrayList com valores de outro ArrayList pegos aleatoriamente?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Tenho a classe `Vetor` que terá um método para iniciar um vetor com números aleatórios:

```
public class Vetor{
    private int tamanho;
    private int[] vetor;

    public Vetor(int tamanho) {
       this.tamanho = tamanho;
       this.vetor = vetor;
    }

    public void iniciaVetor() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
           this.vetor[i] = (int) Math.random();
        }
    }
}
```

Agora tenho a classe `Arraylist` que terá um método para comportar um *array* de vetores:

```
public class Arraylist{
    private int tamanho;
    private ArrayList<Vetor> arraylist;

    public Arraylist(int tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void iniciaArray(int tamanho_vetor) {
        Vetor v;
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho_vetor; i++) {
            v = new Vetor(tamanho_vetor);
            v.iniciaVetor();
            arraylist.add(v);
        }
    }   
}
```

Por fim, tenho a classe **seleciona** que tem um método que irá selecionar aleatoriamente um índice (um vetor entre a lista de vetores) e irá preencher esse vetor na lista `temp`. Irá terminar até o `temp` ter o mesmo tamanho do `arraylist`.

```
public class Selecao{
    public ArrayList<Vetor> seleciona(ArrayList<Vetor> arraylist, tamanho_vetor) {
        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList<>();
        while (arraylist.size() != temp.size()) {
            int numero_aleatorio = (int) Math.random();
            //cromo adicionar o vetor da posição "numero_aleatorio" no arraylist temp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Criar um `ArrayList` com base em outro `ArrayList` é simples: `List<AlgumaCoisa> a = ...; List<AlgumaCoisa> b = new ArrayList<>(a);` - entretanto, isso é o que o título da sua questão pede. Já o que o conteúdo da sua questão pede, me pareceu bem confuso. Recomendo a você descrever textualmente o que você está tentando fazer ao invés de já partir para o código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código tem várias bandeiras vermelhas, mas vou focar só no que precisa para a pergunta.

O que deseja é embaralhar o *array*. O Java tem isso pronto. Use o método [`shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-). Nem precisa criar um método para isto, mas se quiser criar uma abstração pode fazê-lo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) lista.add(i);
         seleciona(lista);
         for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) System.out.println(lista.get(i));
    }
    public static void seleciona(ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {
        Collections.shuffle(arraylist);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5pqG4P). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rjdxdwqk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/Shuffle.java).

Eu coloquei um `Integer` na lista, mas poderia ser qualquer outra coisa. Só fiz assim para facilitar já que a pergunta não tinha um código fácil para testar.

Com o comentário abaixo ficou mais claro e fiz esta solução:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) lista.add(i);
         lista = seleciona(lista);
         for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) System.out.println(lista.get(i));
    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> seleciona(ArrayList<Integer> arraylist) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(arraylist.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
            temp.add(arraylist.get(rnd.nextInt(arraylist.size())));
        }
        return temp;
    }

}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gvpL2V). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tnqjlmoa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/PickRandom.java).

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Mas não quero que apenas embaralhe o arraylist. Eu realmente quero que retorne um arraylist preenchido com vetores aleatórios do principal, não importa se for repetido ou não. Ex:
Vamor supor que o seja sorteado o vetor de número 6. Nele contém 1, 5, 3, 8, 6. Eu quero que esses valores sejam preenchidos na primeira posição do arraylist temp. Depois sorteia outro vetor e assim por diante. Repare que não importa se cair novamente o vetor número 6, se ele cair, terei que preencher em temp assim mesmo em outro índice.

Comment: @Rrr fiz como está falando agora.